# Applying style to activity

Tags: android

I want to apply a style to my app once I select the app preference.

Here is the relevant section in my MainActivity.java :

```
 private void loadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean Background = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("background_color", false);
    if (Background){
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);

    }
```

^I want to apply the style in the (Background) portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead with this and use your color instead of WHITE.

```
 if (Background){
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);
        mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 }
```

Comment: where do i add this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can set the style programatically. However you can get around it using template layout xml or you can create your custom class for views